# Как в получаемом JSON от WordPress сделать unset ненужных полей

Tags: wordpress

Есть такая ссылка http://udeveloper.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=9, которая возвращает в json записи из рубрики с id=9.

Получается что-то такое (большой текст изменил для упрощения):

```
[
  {
    "id": 80,
    "date": "2017-12-07T20:32:21",
    "date_gmt": "2017-12-07T17:32:21",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://site.ru/?p=80"
    },
    "modified": "2017-12-07T20:46:54",
    "modified_gmt": "2017-12-07T17:46:54",
    "slug": "kak-sdelat-shablon-s-nulja-dlja-joomla-3-x-stranica-error-404",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "http://site.ru/joomla/kak-sdelat-shablon-s-nulja-dlja-joomla-3-x-stranica-error-404.html",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Как сделать шаблон с нуля для Joomla 3.x (Страница &#171;error 404&#187;)"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "ТЕКТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТСТ",
      "protected": false
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "ТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТ",
      "protected": false
    },
    "author": 1,
    "featured_media": 81,
    "comment_status": "open",
    "ping_status": "open",
    "sticky": false,
    "template": "",
    "format": "standard",
    "meta": [],
    "categories": [
      9
    ],
    "tags": [
      16,
      17,
      18
    ],
    "featured_image_thumbnail_url": "http://site.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Kak-sdelat-shablon-s-nulja-dlja-Joomla-3.x-Stranica-error-404.jpg",
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "http://site.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/80"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "http://site.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "http://site.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
        }
      ],
      "author": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://site.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
        }
      ],
      "replies": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://site.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=80"
        }
      ],
      "version-history": [
        {
          "href": "http://site.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/80/revisions"
        }
      ],
      "wp:featuredmedia": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://site.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/media/81"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "http://site.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=80"
        }
      ],
      "wp:term": [
        {
          "taxonomy": "category",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://site.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=80"
        },
        {
          "taxonomy": "post_tag",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://site.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=80"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Также мне подсказали функцию, которая добавляет в json ссылки на картинки записей

```
function my_rest_prepare_post( $data, $post, $request ) {
    $_data                                 = $data->data;
    $thumbnail_id                          = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    $thumbnail                             = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'full' );
    $_data['featured_image_thumbnail_url'] = $thumbnail[0];
    $data->data                            = $_data;

    return $data;
}

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'my_rest_prepare_post', 10, 3 );
```

Как можно убрать из JSON ненужные поля? И например в json получаются массивы title и content а в них ключи rendered, которые и содержит заголовок и сам контент. Можно ли упростить и чтобы в готовом json были ключи title и content с данными (без вложенных ключей)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой код в functions.php

```
function my_rest_prepare_post( $data, $post, $request ) {
    // Получаем данные
    $new_data = $data;
    $_data = $new_data->data;

    // Добавляем изображение записи
    $thumbnail_id                          = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    $thumbnail                             = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'full' );
    $_data['featured_image_thumbnail_url'] = $thumbnail[0];

    // Убираем ссылки из объекта WP_REST_Response
    $links = $new_data->get_links();
    foreach ( $links as $key => $value ) {
        $new_data->remove_link( $key );
    }

    // Убираем ненужные поля
    unset( $_data['id'] );
    unset( $_data['date'] );
    unset( $_data['date_gmt'] );
    unset( $_data['guid'] );
    unset( $_data['modified'] );
    unset( $_data['modified_gmt'] );
    unset( $_data['slug'] );
    unset( $_data['status'] );
    unset( $_data['type'] );
    unset( $_data['link'] );
    $title = $_data['title']['rendered'];
    unset( $_data['title'] );
    $_data['title'] = $title;
    $content        = $_data['content']['rendered'];
    unset( $_data['content'] );
    $_data['content'] = $content;
    unset( $_data['excerpt'] );
    unset( $_data['author'] );
    unset( $_data['featured_media'] );
    unset( $_data['comment_status'] );
    unset( $_data['ping_status'] );
    unset( $_data['sticky'] );
    unset( $_data['template'] );
    unset( $_data['format'] );
    unset( $_data['meta'] );
    unset( $_data['categories'] );
    unset( $_data['tags'] );

    // Возвращаем данные
    $new_data->data = $_data;

    return $new_data;
}

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'my_rest_prepare_post', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо большое.